# cf_payflowpro installation

Tags: coldfusion, payflowpro

I've inherited a little code that uses this custom tag:

```
<cf_payflowpro 
 query="RESULT"
 hostaddress="pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com"
 hostport="443" 
 timeout="30"
 pwd="#hpword#"
 partner="#hpartner#"
 vendor="xxxxxx"
 trxtype="#callPP#" 
 tender="C" 
 acct="#form.card_number#" 
 expdate="#form.expire_month##form.expire_year#" 
 amt="#form.card_amount#"
 cvv2="#form.cvv2#"
 name="#cardholder#" 
 street="#cardstreet#" 
 city="#cardcity#" 
 state="#cardstate#" 
 zip="#card_zip#" 
 comment1="#card_comment1#" 
 comment2="#card_comment2#" 
 email="#card_email#"
 >
```

I'm very new to cold fusion.  I suspect that the custom tag is form here:  http://cf_payflowpro.riaforge.org/ but I'm not 100% sure.  I downloaded it.  It has a file in it PayFlowPro.cfm.  How and where do I install this?

Comment: FYI, that tag uses an API that's no longer supported. Here's a simple CFC that wraps the HTTP interface: http://github.com/pmcelhaney/payflowpro-api-for-coldfusion

Comment: Patrick thats incorrect, the tag above (CF_PayFlowPro) uses the modern, http connection method.  You may be thinking of the older CFX_PayFlowPro tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Creating and calling custom tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00001071.htm) on the ColdFusion docs. Quote:

> **Storing custom tag pages**
>
> You must store custom tag pages in any one of the following:
>
> - The same directory as the calling page
> - The cfusion\CustomTags directory
> - A subdirectory of the cfusion\CustomTags directory
> - A directory that you specify in the ColdFusion MX Administrator

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article about [how to install custom tags](http://www.electricsheep.co.nz/library/customtags.cfm).  It has been a while, but if you have a global directory in the project, I think you can just drop it in there too...